# SQL Server 2017 Encryption

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2017

I am migration an On Prem database server to Azure. All migration is completed but we are stuck at encryption. We have a symmetric key decrypted by a certificate and the certificate is decrypted by the master key. The problem is I am able to open the master key but not the symmetric key. I did research on internet but not able to find anything. Just to try my luck I restored the database again but the encryption is again not working. I also tried dropping the master key, certificate and the symmetric key and created a new. This time I was able to open the symmetric key but encryption is still not working. When I am decrypting the encrypted column I am getting null values.

I am using this for decrypting:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY NameOfSymmetricKey
         DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE NameOfCertificate;

         Select EncryptDOB,  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR    (MAX),DecryptByKeyAutoCert    (cert_ID('NameOfCertificate'), NULL,     EncryptDOB)),'1900-01-01') As 'DateOfBirth'
  from TableName

  CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY NameOfSymmetricKey;
```

Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The encryption is working now but the problem is it is working only in the session in which I am opening the master key. If I open other session and try to decrypt, I still get null values against the encrypted column. Why is it that when I am opening the master key, its only opening for that session?

Comment: I am getting this when I try to decrypt: Msg 15581, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.

(6400 rows affected)
Msg 15315, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The key 'PrismSymmetricKey' is not open. Please open the key before using it.